# Improving the efficiency of concurrent processes - set CPU limit or something else?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, cpu

I am writing a PHP-based website one of which tasks involves accepting a zip file containing images sent by a user, unzipping it and creating thumbnails for each unzipped image. Since doing this on-the-fly with PHP would be really painful (the server machine is slow, and PHP itself is not the fastest language out there) I have come up with a solution using C with ImageMagick to handle the images. The C program is notified by PHP through Unix Sockets that there is a new job coming. The C program itself has 4 child processes, each being a task handler capable of unzipping the archive and handling the images. A problem has arisen, however: this image resizing takes up so much CPU that the system literally freezes. Even one instance of the program consumes more than 50%, and if there are many concurrent processes the system just becomes irresponsive. The system load generated by just one process is acceptable, although the whole system becomes quite inefficient then, since only one task can be processed at a time; therefore I would like to have at least three concurrent processes.

Now I want to ask the actual question: is there a (not overly complicated) way to set a limit on the CPU usage by a process, or should I try something else? And if I manage to set the limit, doesn't it defeat the point of concurrency? Maybe I should be using a more efficient library? (although I think ImageMagick is not a bad choice, is it?) If not that, what other solutions could you suggest?

Note: the system is a 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [nice](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-the-nice-value-of-a-process/)?

Comment: For some reason it has absolutely no effect. I've tried both changing nice from within the program (nice(19)) and running it from shell with the priority specified (like /usr/bin/nice -n 19 my_program). Still using up way too much processing power.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is wise to fork new processes for the creation of thumbnails. I guess it is cheaper to use PHP's ImageMagick functions in general and it will not be significantly slower. Have you tested that?
Do you use the -thumbnail operator of the convert command?

Comment: No, I have written my own piece of software in C using the library.